# Disable cache in Pylons app under development mode

Tags: python, pylons

I'm using `@beaker_cache()` decorator in my Pylons application.
How can I disable the cache under development mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own decorator which looks at pylons.config["debug"], and depending on that either returns function unchanged or decorated with beaker_cache. Something along these lines (completely untested!):

```
from pylons import config

def my_cache(*args, **kwargs):
    if config["debug"]:
        decorate = lambda f: f
    else: 
        decorate = beaker_cache(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorate
```